# Same for with different behavior in Django

Tags: html, django, templates, for-loop

I have a little question, and it's about for loop in Django template:

I want to do a for and in each iteration do something different for example

```
{% for object in objects %}

##### html code to put a div with object information in the left and one in the right ######

{% endfor %}
```

To print all my objects but one in the left and another one in the right.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

You want the [cycle tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#cycle).

```
{% for object in objects %}
  <li class="{% cycle "your-left-class" "your-right-class" %}">
    {{object}}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
{% for object in objects %}
   <div class="
      {% if forloop.counter % 2 == 0 %}
         pull-left
      {% else %}
         pull-right
     {% endif %}
   ">
      {{object}}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Check the [for loop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) in templates.

Comment: I suggest using inline styles in your example rather than assuming the OP is using Bootstrap.

Comment: I used like this:                                                             {% if forloop.counter % 2 == 0 %}
   <li>
{% else %}
<li class="timeline-inverted">
{% endif %} but it says: Could not parse the remainder: '%' from '%'

Comment: Django templates do not support `%` as the mod operator. You could use the [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#divisibleby) tag. However using the `cycle` tag as @patsweet suggests is more idiomatic.